# mvn install crashes jvm

Tags: java, maven

I am facing a strange thing while running mvn install for a project. While executing the **Copying webapp resources** step the JVM crashed. I get a windows pop up saying Java has stopped working. I am not getting any error message in the console so that I can get hold of the root cause. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps :

```
1. Use JDK instead of JRE in Installed JREs. 
   Eclipse Path (Windows--Preference--Java--Installed JREs )
2. Use this option for maven : 
   clean install -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true 
   (in Run As Maven Build --- Goals)
```

[Try to find the JVM crash report if available in your machine]

Comment: I can access javaw.exe.10828.dmp files. But not sure how to check them to get the root cause

Comment: @AritraRoy Use a online debugger tool if possible to analyze the thread dump file.